# Isa. 65:11—troop/fortune, number/destiny

Tags: idolatry

> KJV: prepare a table for that **troop**, … furnish  the drink offering  unto that **number**
> NIV: spread a table for **Fortune** … fill bowls … for **Destiny**

Brown/Driver/Briggs suggests that the bolded words refer to false gods.  Are there other words (proper nouns) we could use to get more information about these (nonexistent) entities?  Or a commentary that addresses this?

I supposedly have several commentaries installed in e-sword-X but I haven’t figured out how to access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is a little collection of standard commentaries available here >>  https://biblehub.com/commentaries/isaiah/65-11.htm

The BSB has this as a footnote to Isa 65:11 -

> But you who forsake the LORD, who forget My holy mountain, who set a
> table for **Fortune**(d) and fill bowls of mixed wine for **Destiny**
> (e),
>
> 11 (d) Hebrew Gad, the Babylonian god of fortune
>
> 11 (e) Hebrew Meni, the Babylonian god of fate

Ellicott offers these comments:

> That prepare a table for that troop.—Hebrew, “for the Gad,” probably
> the planet Jupiter, worshipped as the “greater fortune,” the giver of
> good luck. The LXX. renders “for the demon” or “Genius.” The name of
> Baal-Gad (Joshua 11:17; Joshua 12:17) indicates the early prevalence
> of the worship in Syria. Phœnician inscriptions have been found with
> the names Gad-Ashtoreth and Gad-Moloch. The “table” points to the
> lectisternium (or “feast”), which was a prominent feature in Assyrian
> and other forms of polytheism.

The Cambridge commentary is similar:

> **that prepare a table &c**. Better: that spread a table for Gad, and fill up mixed wine (see ch. Isaiah 5:22) to Meni. The rites described
> are the lectisternia, well known throughout the ancient world, in
> which a table was spread, furnished with meats and drinks as a meal
> for the gods (Liv. Isaiah 5:13; Herodot. 1:183; Ep. of Jeremiah , vv.
> 27 f.; Bel and the Dragon, v. 11; cf. Jeremiah 7:18; Jeremiah 19:13;
> Jeremiah 44:17, 1 Corinthians 10:21).

Barnes is also similar:

> Grotius supposes that the name Gad means the same as the goddess
> Fortune, which was worshipped by the Hebrews, Chaldeans, and Arabians;
> and that Meni means a divinity of that name, which Strabo says was
> worshipped in Armenia and Phrygia. Other opinions may be seen in
> Vitringa. That two idols are intended here, there can be no doubt.
> For,
>
> 1. The circumstance mentioned of their preparing a table for them, and pouring out a drink-offering, is expressive of idolatry.
> 2. The connection implies this, as the reproof in this chapter is to a considerable extent for their idolatry.
> 3. The universal opinion of expositors, though they have varied in regard to the idols intended, proves this.
>
> Aben Ezra, Kimchi, and the rabbis generally suppose that by Gad the
> planet Jupiter was intended, which they say was worshipped throughout
> the East as the god of fortune, and this is now the prevalent opinion.

See the above link for far more information.

Comment: Thanks for the BibleHub link.  I kew they had commentaries, but I didn't find a link where I thought I had remembered it.

Answer (score 1):

We have no other source for these two names of false deities in the Scriptures and are dependent of ancient sources to identify them.

```
  But as for you who forsake the LORD, 
  Who ignore My holy mountain, 
  Who set a table for Luck 
  And fill a mixing bowl for Destiny:
     [footnotes have "Names of heathen deities"]
          (Isa. 65:11, JPS1985)
```

> 65:11. Fortune/Destiny. The proper (divine?) names used here, Gad (NIV: “Fortune”) and Meni (NIV: “Destiny”), are obscure. Gad is attested in Canaanite and Phoenician texts and is considered a good luck deity. Meni may have something to do with portion, and therefore some have thought that it may have had something to do with fate or fortune. It may have been the same as the Arabian goddess Manat mentioned in the Qu’ran. In the Babylonian pantheon the god Namtar (“Destiny”) was the vizier of the netherworld. Fate was also at times personified and deified.
> --
> Matthews, V. H., Chavalas, M. W., & Walton, J. H. (2000). *The IVP Bible background commentary: Old Testament* (electronic ed., Is 65:11). InterVarsity Press.

> [11–16] Verse 11 picks up the theme of the apostates, those who forsook rather than sought Yahweh. The two deities referred to as Gad and Meni—often rendered as Fortune and Destiny—were most probably gods of fate. Gad was a Syrian deity whose name is preserved in various place names such as Baalgad (Josh. 11:17). Meni is less familiar, but thought to be venerated by the Arabs in the pre-Islamic period. Pettinato claims to have found reference to Meni at Ebla (cf. literature cited by Koenen, 180). The biblical text appears to refer to some form of sacred meal that further extends the accusations against the pagan practices in 65:3ff. The theme of not responding to God’s call of v. 1 is once again continued in v. 12 in order to lay stress on the deliberate rejection of God’s invitation.
> --
> Childs, B. S. (2001). *Isaiah: A Commentary* (W. P. Brown, C. A. Newsom, & B. A. Strawn, Eds.; 1st ed., pp. 536–537). Westminster John Knox Press.

> “Who set a table for Gad”—who prepare a repast for Gad, the deity of good fortune whose name is known from inscriptions, seals, and proper names in Ugaritic, Amorite, Punic, Aramaic, Phoenician, Nabatean, Arabic, and Hebrew. [a long list of original resources here.]...  מְנִי is usually identified as the god Manūtu/Manāt, who was worshiped by the Nabateans and early Arabs. (See S. D. Sperling, “Meni,” in van der Toorn et al., eds., Dictionary of Deities and Demons, 566–68; and for Israelite names with מני as a theophoric element, see Tigay, You Shall Have No Other Gods, 13, 67.) For Hebrew מנת, denoting one’s “portion” in life, hence destiny, see Jer 13:25; Ps 11:6. Note the assonance of the fivefold mem in the three consecutive words in this stich and two more in the first colon of the next verse.
> --
> Paul, S. M. (2012). *Isaiah 40–66: Translation and Commentary* (p. 599-600). William B. Eerdmans Publishing Company.